# Why isn't the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of the uniform distribution at $s = 0$ equal to 1?

Tags: probability, laplace-transform, uniform-distribution

I've been studying the **Laplace-Stieltjes** transform and I noticed that, according to the definition, the Laplace transform of any probability distribution at point $s = 0$ should be 1.

The transform for a random variable $X$ can be defined as:

$$X^*(s) = E[e^{-sX}]$$

Hence, at point $s = 0$, $X^*(0) = E[e^{-0X}] = E[1] = 1$.

This holds true for most distributions, except the uniform distribution. The Laplace-Stieltjes for the uniform distribution on the interval $(a,b)$ is given by:

$$U^*(s) = E[e^{-sU}] = \int_{a}^{b} e^{-su} \frac{1}{b-a}du = \frac{e^{-sa} - e^{-sb}}{s(b-a)}$$

Which at $s = 0$ is *undefined* (or so I think). My question is: why isn't it 1 (the definition leads me to believe it should be one)? Is there something incorrect with my train of thought?

Comment: You still get 1 in the limit.  You can use L'Hopital to show this.

Comment: Are you asking about the continuity of $X^*$ at $s=0$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b e^{-{\bf 0} u } du = ? $

Comment: Fnacool is correct.  The definition is an integral, so evaluate *that* at the special value: $$U^*(0) ~=~ \mathsf E(e^{-0U})~=~1$$  (Though using L'Hopital's rule as Paul suggested will *also* obtain the required result.)